# How do I flush custom URL cache in my browser?

Tags: caching, browser

We have an app that uses a custom URL scheme like myapp://foo to authorize via a third party app and then reopen the app fully authenticated. Now we also use the same custom URL scheme myapp:// for another app, but when I authenticate with the other app, it will open the old app.

Apparently this is the browser remembering what to do with myapp:// requests, but I would like to know when this cache will expire, how I can see it and how to flush it.

update: I couldn't find a way except for going into browser preferences file and deleting the entry manually. Looks like there is no other way.

Comment: It's reserved name space for protocol name. Nice Q but I am not sure for this.

Comment: _“Now we also use the same custom URL scheme myapp:// for another app”_ - why??? That’s like naming both your dogs by the exact same name, and now you are wondering why you can’t call them individually any more ... well, d’uh?

Comment: @CBroe true dat. But it's actually one qt component inside another - so sometimes we just want to run the component as an app and sometimes we want to run the whole app.